# javascript function works without argument,

Tags: javascript, function

```
function change_tag(url){
  $('.filter_button_confirm').unbind('click').on('click', function(){
    ...
    console.log(url);

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        ...
      },
      beforeSend: function(){
        ...
      }
    })
      .done(function(data){
        ...
      })
  });
};
```

When I call the function with argument `change_tag('/some_url/')` of course it works.

But, `change_tag()` also works perfectly.

It brings data from the url that I set in the past.

`console.log(url)` shows 'undefined' so I don't know how it knows the url.

Comment: What do you want the solution to be? Should the code throw an error if no `url` is given?

Comment: What if you rename your parameter 'url', to check if you are not using a global variable ?

Comment: Did you declare `url` globally?

Comment: I want to know how it works. I'm afraid error occurs later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're not passing in a parameter to the function, `url` is `undefined` and so the ajax call gets called with `url: undefined`. This is the same as not providing an url, and makes it post to the url you're currently on.

For more info you can check the jQuery page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Calling `change_tag()` actually calls `change_tag` with `url` as `undefined`, not `null`.

Comment: But the OP says that the console log shows `undefined` for the URL and adds that "It brings data from the url that I set in the past.", not the current URL